# Pagination with per-row access rights

Tags: pagination, couchdb, nosql

Hi I am using CouchDB and assuming I have an `articles` document with the field `users`, containing an array of user IDs that are allowed to view this article.

Example scenario, there will be a paginated table view showing 10 articles per page, my controller will retrieve the first 10 articles from CouchDB then perform the access rights check one by one on the returned articles. But the current user may only have view access rights on say, 8 of them, therefore the table will only show 8 articles instead of 10.

**What are the best practice of handling such situation besides implementing the access rights logic on the CouchDB layer?**

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I would simply use a view keyed on the `users` field:

```
function (doc) {
  doc.users.forEach(function (user) {
    emit([ user ]);
  });
}
```

I emitted an array with just 1 item in this case. I presume you'd also emit something like `doc.created` in order to have your articles sorted, you would simply add them after `user` in that array.

The view results would look something like:

```
{
  "rows": [
    { "id": "<article-1>", "key": [ "<user-1>", "<created>" ] },
    { "id": "<article-2>", "key": [ "<user-1>", "<created>" ] },
    { "id": "<article-3>", "key": [ "<user-1>", "<created>" ] },
    { "id": "<article-1>", "key": [ "<user-2>", "<created>" ] },
    { "id": "<article-1>", "key": [ "<user-3>", "<created>" ] }
  ]
}
```

You can simply paginate like you normally would with CouchDB. You simply use `start_key=["<user-1>"]&end_key=["<user-1>","\ufff0"]` in addition to the usual paging `limit=10&skip=0` for page 1, `limit=10&skip=10` for page 2, etc.